# How to select all elements not containing block elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am frustrated with so much of gray text on many web pages, which doesn't give me enough contrast. I want ordinary text black on all pages. Setting

```
* {
  color: black;
}
```

in chrome/userContent.css is a bit too much, though. Some text may have other colors, but text in elements containing only inline elements - or those not containing further block elements - should be black. I want to override all the gray text settings.

Or is there a different way to achieve this? Using some addon would only be second choice.

Comment: basically you cannot with CSS as you don't have a way to test if an element is block or not

Comment: in case you have style attribute:https://jsfiddle.net/be1uwngk/1/

Comment: It's about all web pages I load - not my own ones. So I cannot adjust the HTML or the CSS of the page, just add something to chrome/userContent.css.